# Máscara para formatação de TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Estava praticando a programar em um projeto do tipo *WinForms*, logo surgiu uma dúvida: Como aplicar uma máscara de telefone em um *TextBox*. Então a primeira coisa que me veio a cabeça foi usar o evento *KeyPress* do componente.

A lógica do código ficou simples, segue abaixo...

```
private void cbTelefone_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string numero = Convert.ToString(cbTelefone.Text);

        if (numero.Length <= 10) // Telefone Fixo com DDD
        {
            string numeroTelefoneFixo = Convert.ToString(cbTelefone.Text);
            cbTelefone.Text = String.Format(@"{0:(00)0000-0000}", numeroTelefoneFixo);
        }
        else if (numero.Length == 11) // Celular com DDD
        {
            string numeroTelefoneCelular = Convert.ToString(cbTelefone.Text);
            cbTelefone.Text = String.Format(@"{0:(00)00000-0000}", numeroTelefoneCelular);
        }
```

O *TextBox* não está recebendo a máscara do telefone. O que devo fazer para solucionar?

Comment: Por que você não usa um MaskedTextBox?

Comment: Inicialmente o MaskedTextBox não possui formatação no padrão de telefones usado no Brasil, então acredito eu que teria que desenvolver um código parecido com este usando o MaskedTextBox

Comment: @Leonardo o `MaskedTextBox` permite alterar a máscara por omissão, é só colocar da mesma forma que está a colocar no seu `String.Format`.

Comment: @JoãoMartins, mas em todo caso teria que validar se o número é um celular (11 dígitos com DDD) ou fixo (10 dígitos com DDD), então ao meu ver, o código será igual ao que eu fiz utilizando o TextBox

Comment: Mas esse tipo de validação só a consegue fazer depois do utilizador acabar de introduzir o texto, caso contrário não saberá qual o tamanho, se 10 ou 11. Se não é possível perceber de antemão se o número terá 10 ou 11 dígitos, diria que não é possível aplicar uma máscara...

Comment: Mudei o evento para onLeave, coloquei um Breakpoint no evento, digitei 10 números ... Quando saí componente pude observar no resultado das variáveis que a string não está sendo formatada, ou seja, ela continua com o mesmo valor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema estará no facto de o `String.Format` não conseguir converter uma `String` para um formato numérico.

Experimente converter o número de telefone que vem da `TextBox` para um número e depois aplicar a máscara:

```
string AplicarMascaraTelefone(string strNumero)
{
    // por omissão tem 10 ou menos dígitos
    string strMascara = "{0:(00)0000-0000}";
    // converter o texto em número
    long lngNumero = Convert.ToInt64(strNumero);

    if (strNumero.Length == 11)
        strMascara = "{0:(00)00000-0000}";

    return string.Format(strMascara, lngNumero);
}
```

De salientar que este método deverá apenas ser chamado no `Leave`, não irá funcionar corretamente no `KeyPress`, como já debatemos nos comentários da sua questão.

Comment: Obrigado João, o tipo da variável estava errado. Funcionou após a troca :)